# No menu for 'Add to my Page' after creating canvas?

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas

If I create a canvas and open the app profile page, It is showing a new look taking the left side area and there is no menu for 'Add to my Page'. What am I doing wrong? I am just unable to include a tab to a page.

I am trying to create an app to run my iframe, I used the following settings.

Apps On Facebook:

- Canvas URL - Enter (http://YOURAPPLICATIONID.iframehost.com/)
- Secure Canvas URL: (https://YOURAPPLICATIONID.iframehost.com/)

Page Tab:

- Tab URL - Enter http://(YOURAPPLICATIONID.iframehost.com/tab)
- Secure Tab URL- Enter (https://YOURAPPLICATIONID.iframehost.com/tab)

However there docent appear to be a way to "Add to my page" from the app profile page. I am following this tutorial.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoLpR2u7Ul8

Answer (score 8):

Use the following to add to your facebook page:

http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=[APP-ID]&pages=1

Replace [APP-ID] with your app id

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I installed my app on about 50 clients, and every once in a while I have to spend hours to find out how to add the app to a page after Facebook new changes. Where is it in Facebook documentation?

Comment: The old www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab URL no longer works for me, but this URL definitely still works, just used it

Answer (score 1):

Facebook are continuously changing things so most of the non-FB documentation and tutorials get outdated very quickly (which is a pain because they are much easier to understand than FBs own documentation!)

This time they're changing how the App Profile pages work, and some changed have been made since last week. You can find out the new way of adding your page here:
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-removing-app-profile-pages-on-feb-1-2012/

Basically, you need to

1. Use the "Create Facebook Page" button in the edit app page

and either:

2 Create a link for others to add your tab using code similar this:

```
<a href="#" onclick=window.open("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=176217385757369&next=http://tabpressapp.phpfogapp.com/content/pages/","PageTab","width=800,height=500");>Add TabPress to Your Fan Page!</a>
```

or 3. For your own private use code similar to this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=176217385757369&next=http://tabpressapp.phpfogapp.com/content/pages/
```

(replacing with your own app_id & nexturl obviously!) 
**Edit:** forgot to mention, the url for "next" is either the “Canvas URL” or “Page Tab URL” you used in your edit app page.

I haven't had to do this myself yet, but please let me know how it goes because I will soon!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

Where YOUR_URL = the website address where you upload the HTML files.

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/